# How to set the width of the Y-Axis labels?

Tags: lightningchart

I have 2 charts added to a dashboard, and sharing a common custom cursor.
How do I make sure the width of the columns displaying the Y-Axis ticks have the same width, (so that the custom cursor line matches up perfectly)?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to explicitly configure the thickness of both Y axes to the same pixel value.

```
chart1.getDefaultAxisY().setThickness(140)
chart2.getDefaultAxisY().setThickness(140)
```